# Is there a way to send files through ajax without FormData or a form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, file-upload

I'm using BackboneJS and I was wondering if I could just do `model.save` and add in all the data I need including the files.
For example:

```
model.set({
    field1: 'info1'
    files: ['some array with files']
});

model.save();
```

Is 64bits encoding a viable solution? Even if it worked, I'm worried about performance.

Comment: "Even if it worked, I'm worried about performance." --- you're worried about performance of something you have not measured since it does not even work. o_O

Comment: As in "I've tried 64bits encoding before (not with uploading a file) and it takes a while"